# Sharepoint Web analytics configuration wrong web application

Tags: 2010, central-administration, web-application, web-analytics

I've tried to configure Sharepoint web analytics on the web application on my development machine but without success. I've followed various guides on the internet including runing some timer jobs and changing the date on the server to check.

No luck.

Today I found out that the service i working fine on the web app where central admin runs, but it still doesn't work on the web app my site collection is.

I've checked the web application "Service connection" and the web analytics service is listed and checked (actually every service is checked).

Anyone can help me?

EDIT:

These are the logs agter running "Web analytics Trigger workflow timer job"

```
05/24/2013 09:08:00.00  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1C50  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-blocking-query-provider)    6b52a70a-3f70-483e-9126-da5dd7ccbed5
05/24/2013 09:08:00.00  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1C50  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-blocking-query-provider). Execution Time=6.37055690660786    6b52a70a-3f70-483e-9126-da5dd7ccbed5
05/24/2013 09:08:00.00  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1544  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-workflow)   921235cc-2da1-4041-9e45-2ca66f03d6a5
05/24/2013 09:08:00.01  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x238C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-sql-memory-provider)    5c974c0f-2aff-4df8-a44a-3c367f69c6fb
05/24/2013 09:08:00.01  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x14D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job User Profile Service Application_LanguageSynchronizationJob)    558eddb7-9e2d-4b04-80ac-bb7e10fa9981
05/24/2013 09:08:00.01  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x238C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-sql-memory-provider). Execution Time=10.5877061725326    5c974c0f-2aff-4df8-a44a-3c367f69c6fb
05/24/2013 09:08:00.02  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job User Profile Service Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob) e4035294-9437-4c23-967f-c577c7aca9a8
05/24/2013 09:08:00.02  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x14D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job User Profile Service Application_LanguageSynchronizationJob). Execution Time=11.5626461816985    558eddb7-9e2d-4b04-80ac-bb7e10fa9981
05/24/2013 09:08:00.02  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1544  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-workflow). Execution Time=20.7019378296649   921235cc-2da1-4041-9e45-2ca66f03d6a5
05/24/2013 09:08:00.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job User Profile Service Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob). Execution Time=21.5089319686387 e4035294-9437-4c23-967f-c577c7aca9a8
05/24/2013 09:08:01.80  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2560  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service)   51342931-8e68-44ea-8cb7-6f4a7652f9f9
05/24/2013 09:08:01.80  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2560  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  dkd5    High        synchronizing search service instance   51342931-8e68-44ea-8cb7-6f4a7652f9f9
05/24/2013 09:08:01.80  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2560  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  eff0    High        synchronizing search data access service instance   51342931-8e68-44ea-8cb7-6f4a7652f9f9
05/24/2013 09:08:01.94  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2560  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  dl2i    Medium      Search application 'Search Service Application': Provision start addresses in default content source.   51342931-8e68-44ea-8cb7-6f4a7652f9f9
05/24/2013 09:08:01.95  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2560  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service). Execution Time=169.116747049798   51342931-8e68-44ea-8cb7-6f4a7652f9f9
05/24/2013 09:08:08.49  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=13e07c9e%2Dc5c0%2D414c%2Db148%2D1b8fdaf02723&Source=%2F%5Fadmin%2FServiceJobDefinitions%2Easpx%3FPageIndex%3D1))  
05/24/2013 09:08:08.49  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=13e07c9e%2Dc5c0%2D414c%2Db148%2D1b8fdaf02723&Source=%2F%5Fadmin%2FServiceJobDefinitions%2Easpx%3FPageIndex%3D1)   73097afd-dd31-46a9-9ecf-351ffd92ccdc
05/24/2013 09:08:08.50  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  73097afd-dd31-46a9-9ecf-351ffd92ccdc
05/24/2013 09:08:08.53  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=13e07c9e%2Dc5c0%2D414c%2Db148%2D1b8fdaf02723&Source=%2F%5Fadmin%2FServiceJobDefinitions%2Easpx%3FPageIndex%3D1)). Execution Time=37.0325388007147 73097afd-dd31-46a9-9ecf-351ffd92ccdc
05/24/2013 09:08:08.59  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1D6C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://sp2010dev:32843/48646a8173434735b2fe6a4af9b1a37e/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:e2ed6c1c-072c-40e8-85ad-6f5e15ed1bfd'    
05/24/2013 09:08:08.60  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://sp2010dev.virtualsp.dev:32843/48646a8173434735b2fe6a4af9b1a37e/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:e2ed6c1c-072c-40e8-85ad-6f5e15ed1bfd'    07774c8f-6d81-40fb-8c5e-e7b1a0b26659
05/24/2013 09:08:08.60  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    07774c8f-6d81-40fb-8c5e-e7b1a0b26659
05/24/2013 09:08:08.60  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc5    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. 07774c8f-6d81-40fb-8c5e-e7b1a0b26659
05/24/2013 09:08:08.60  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc6    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    07774c8f-6d81-40fb-8c5e-e7b1a0b26659
05/24/2013 09:08:08.60  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1.11062509073347    07774c8f-6d81-40fb-8c5e-e7b1a0b26659
05/24/2013 09:08:09.38  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://sp2010dev.virtualsp.dev:32843/48646a8173434735b2fe6a4af9b1a37e/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:1b8d18b0-1697-4ad5-a583-e19a67acf2f9'    8ae2365c-ccb2-4572-a125-97fea08bedac
05/24/2013 09:08:09.38  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    8ae2365c-ccb2-4572-a125-97fea08bedac
05/24/2013 09:08:09.38  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc5    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. 8ae2365c-ccb2-4572-a125-97fea08bedac
05/24/2013 09:08:09.38  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc6    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    8ae2365c-ccb2-4572-a125-97fea08bedac
05/24/2013 09:08:09.39  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x2734  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1,01526599494644    8ae2365c-ccb2-4572-a125-97fea08bedac
05/24/2013 09:08:09.62  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=13e07c9e%2Dc5c0%2D414c%2Db148%2D1b8fdaf02723&Source=%2F%5Fadmin%2FServiceJobDefinitions%2Easpx%3FPageIndex%3D1))     
05/24/2013 09:08:09.62  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=13e07c9e%2Dc5c0%2D414c%2Db148%2D1b8fdaf02723&Source=%2F%5Fadmin%2FServiceJobDefinitions%2Easpx%3FPageIndex%3D1)  eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.62  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (PostAuthenticateRequestHandler). Execution Time=7,08883387686436   eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.64  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WebAnalyticsWorkflowTriggerJobDefinition Name=WebAnalyticsWorkflowTrigger. Version: 504263 Ensure: False, HashCode: 54664230, Id: 13e07c9e-c5c0-414c-b148-1b8fdaf02723, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.RunNow()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.JobEditPage.BtnRunNow_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMa... eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.64* w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...in(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP._admin_jobedit_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.P...  eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.64* w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...rocessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)      eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.67  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=13e07c9e%2Dc5c0%2D414c%2Db148%2D1b8fdaf02723&Source=%2F%5Fadmin%2FServiceJobDefinitions%2Easpx%3FPageIndex%3D1)). Execution Time=55.461039879079 eba0476c-8a84-421f-b1a9-c0668ab4289e
05/24/2013 09:08:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx?PageIndex=1))     
05/24/2013 09:08:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx?PageIndex=1)  b90bd625-7b6b-4b13-be2a-9f94cd2aa6b3
05/24/2013 09:08:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  b90bd625-7b6b-4b13-be2a-9f94cd2aa6b3
05/24/2013 09:08:09.72  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx?PageIndex=1)). Execution Time=49.307294448962 b90bd625-7b6b-4b13-be2a-9f94cd2aa6b3
05/24/2013 09:08:10.14  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x17F4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-timer-locks)    f745f71f-beac-4942-820c-bc747f229cf6
05/24/2013 09:08:10.14  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x17F4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-timer-locks). Execution Time=3.92253235804541    f745f71f-beac-4942-820c-bc747f229cf6
05/24/2013 09:08:13.66  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx))   
05/24/2013 09:08:13.66  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)    401cff81-da12-4024-a402-e5ac51431eb6
05/24/2013 09:08:13.67  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  401cff81-da12-4024-a402-e5ac51431eb6
05/24/2013 09:08:13.72  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1FC0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)). Execution Time=54.7925773618455  401cff81-da12-4024-a402-e5ac51431eb6
05/24/2013 09:08:14.72  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx))   
05/24/2013 09:08:14.72  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)    d5bc668b-e4c0-4f4f-80f1-8838aef3a320
05/24/2013 09:08:14.72  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)). Execution Time=0,535149552476442 d5bc668b-e4c0-4f4f-80f1-8838aef3a320
05/24/2013 09:08:14.73  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx))   
05/24/2013 09:08:14.73  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)    48ce4bcd-d5e4-4a5b-97bf-2515b4d17b70
05/24/2013 09:08:14.73  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)). Execution Time=0,659922896715187 48ce4bcd-d5e4-4a5b-97bf-2515b4d17b70
05/24/2013 09:08:14.73  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx))   
05/24/2013 09:08:14.73  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)    19cd1a7f-8f92-44bc-898b-20bb52b9414e
05/24/2013 09:08:14.73  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  19cd1a7f-8f92-44bc-898b-20bb52b9414e
05/24/2013 09:08:14.78  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)). Execution Time=54.142617355735   19cd1a7f-8f92-44bc-898b-20bb52b9414e
05/24/2013 09:08:15.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2278  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-sql-memory-provider)    0d6abb97-d8ae-4b68-b3f9-abbcfc6fed53
05/24/2013 09:08:15.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x26DC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-blocking-query-provider)    58a777bb-4cb2-4591-a9f1-0de3e45b08fa
05/24/2013 09:08:15.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x26DC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-blocking-query-provider). Execution Time=4.7062797522751 58a777bb-4cb2-4591-a9f1-0de3e45b08fa
05/24/2013 09:08:15.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x2278  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-diagnostics-sql-memory-provider). Execution Time=4.83864387030783    0d6abb97-d8ae-4b68-b3f9-abbcfc6fed53
05/24/2013 09:08:15.81  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx))   
05/24/2013 09:08:15.81  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)    ea90c7b5-ae62-40ca-b332-9d758114361f
05/24/2013 09:08:15.81  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  ea90c7b5-ae62-40ca-b332-9d758114361f
05/24/2013 09:08:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x2248  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)). Execution Time=54.1720316041867  ea90c7b5-ae62-40ca-b332-9d758114361f
05/24/2013 09:08:16.03  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1FD4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job SchedulingApproval) e5a0576c-0a03-4157-adee-c78daf36201c
05/24/2013 09:08:16.03  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1930  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job WebAnalyticsWorkflowTrigger)    4da9530f-e7c2-4a2c-aaf8-5f8d902a4d38
05/24/2013 09:08:16.03  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1930  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        4ohp    High        Enumerating all sites in SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content.    4da9530f-e7c2-4a2c-aaf8-5f8d902a4d38
05/24/2013 09:08:16.03  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1930  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        4ohq    Medium      Site Enumeration Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.get_Names()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAllSitesJobDefinition.Execute(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.WebAnalyticsWorkflowTriggerJobDefinition.Execute(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabaseJobDefinition.Execute(SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)     4da9530f-e7c2-4a2c-aaf8-5f8d902a4d38
05/24/2013 09:08:16.03  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1FD4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job SchedulingApproval). Execution Time=4.63653951804279 e5a0576c-0a03-4157-adee-c78daf36201c
05/24/2013 09:08:16.22  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1930  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job WebAnalyticsWorkflowTrigger). Execution Time=194.487485186131    4da9530f-e7c2-4a2c-aaf8-5f8d902a4d38
05/24/2013 09:08:16.56  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx))   
05/24/2013 09:08:16.56  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)    2c3a9e8f-25a0-4769-a936-9e8cc3ea25a1
05/24/2013 09:08:16.56  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  2c3a9e8f-25a0-4769-a936-9e8cc3ea25a1
05/24/2013 09:08:16.63  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sp2010dev:5555/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx)). Execution Time=68.1480694290125  2c3a9e8f-25a0-4769-a936-9e8cc3ea25a1
05/24/2013 09:08:17.07  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-application-server) aa6c9c95-da98-4013-8831-438c0382341d
05/24/2013 09:08:17.07  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1F70)                       0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-application-server). Execution Time=1.89057709806616 aa6c9c95-da98-4013-8831-438c0382341d
05/24/2013 09:08:18.60  w3wp.exe (0x227C)                           0x1D6C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://sp2010dev:32843/48646a8173434735b2fe6a4af9b1a37e/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:f03d4bb1-485d-42ad-9fdf-f7786830d7ee'    
05/24/2013 09:08:18.61  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://sp2010dev.virtualsp.dev:32843/48646a8173434735b2fe6a4af9b1a37e/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:f03d4bb1-485d-42ad-9fdf-f7786830d7ee'    a94fb17c-d2ed-46ea-8384-e5c85c2aca16
05/24/2013 09:08:18.61  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    a94fb17c-d2ed-46ea-8384-e5c85c2aca16
05/24/2013 09:08:18.61  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc5    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. a94fb17c-d2ed-46ea-8384-e5c85c2aca16
05/24/2013 09:08:18.62  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc6    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    a94fb17c-d2ed-46ea-8384-e5c85c2aca16
05/24/2013 09:08:18.62  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1.19412360246738    a94fb17c-d2ed-46ea-8384-e5c85c2aca16
05/24/2013 09:08:19.47  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://sp2010dev.virtualsp.dev:32843/48646a8173434735b2fe6a4af9b1a37e/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:09353d1d-4228-4e94-929c-2af911163215'    68b025f3-212c-4cf4-99c2-0f63aa712e26
05/24/2013 09:08:19.47  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    68b025f3-212c-4cf4-99c2-0f63aa712e26
05/24/2013 09:08:19.47  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc5    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. 68b025f3-212c-4cf4-99c2-0f63aa712e26
05/24/2013 09:08:19.47  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc6    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    68b025f3-212c-4cf4-99c2-0f63aa712e26
05/24/2013 09:08:19.47  w3wp.exe (0x0C40)                           0x0F78  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1,48921493370882    68b025f3-212c-4cf4-99c2-0f63aa712e26
```

Comment: What is the error message do you see in the screen when you open web analytics reports

Comment: There's no error message, it just indicates that there's not enough data or display 0 as the result

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned running timer jobs and other various attempts to resolve this.

If the data isn't showing up or coming back as a 0 it is possible that it is due to the service that actually compiles the report. Which runs at 5AM and no later than 7AM by default each day. So you may not see results till tomorrow.

Try running the job manually by going to **Central Admin | Monitoring | Timer Jobs | Review job definitions** and find the Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job. Click on the link and opt to "Run Now".

Give it some time and see if your report(s) start to show up or not. IF not, could you please post your ULS logs here after attempting to run the job.

Comment: I've posted the logs as an edit

Comment: Have you configured usage and health data collection for that environment? ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663480(v=office.14).aspx )

Comment: Also I would just double check the configuration steps outlined here on TechNet. ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to answer without any error. It seems like you tried everything. Did you already look at this link:
[Troubleshooting Web Analytics Problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/03/16/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-web-analytics.aspx)

Comment: Followed all the steps, but no luck.